# how to customise the BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME in jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins, continuous-integration, browserstack

I am integrating BrowserStack with the Selenium Python framework and using Jenkin for execution. I am not able to customize the build name in the Browserstack dashboard.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserStack Jenkins plugins are responsible for generating Build name hence you cannot customize.

If you don’t use the BROWSERSTACK_BUILD_NAME environment variable, the plugin will not be able to embed reports in Jenkins.

You can refer to this link: https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/jenkins#viewing-test-report-in-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

In lambdatest I could modify that data by parameter in pipeline groovy, you could try something similar instead of freestyle

Test:

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("build", "alpha_0.1.7");
caps.setCapability("name", "Home page must have a title");
```

In jenkins you can capture the build id or name passing it as a parameter if python allows it. In maven-java I do it as an argument